# Orchard CMS Custom Shape Template for each Item of a Projection Module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms, projection

I am building a web application using **Orchard**, and I am using **Projection** that generates a list content items defined as ***Custom Content Type*** that I gave the name 
**Cotainer-resource**, this content type contais the fields: **​Title (Input Field)**, **​Description (Text Field)** and **Image Url (Text Field)**.

I would like to format each element of the list to use the shape template bellow.
I  am using the Bootstrap theme, and I created the file bellow at the 
*~/Themes/Bootstrap/Views/Content-Cotainer-resource.cshtm*:

```
   @using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-title">
            <h2>
                <span> @Model.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title </span>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="container-content">
                <div>
                    <div class="container-image">
                        <a title="Administração" class="image" href="@Model.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title">
                            <img src="@(Url.Content("../../Resources/images/") + @Model.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title)" alt="container alguma coisa"/></a></div>
                            @Model.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text
                    <div class="assistir ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
                        role="button">
                        <span class="ui-button-text">
                            <a href="/Subject/Subject/Index/@Model.ContentItem.Id">Assistir</a></span></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my placement.info is:

```
<Placement>

    <Place Parts_Title_Summary="Content:1" /> 
    <Place Fields_Common_Text ="Content:2" />
    <Place Parts_Common_Body_Summary = "-" />
    <Place Fields_Input = "-" />

    <Place Parts_Tags_ShowTags = "Content:after.10" /> 
    <Match ContentType="Page">
        <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-" />
    </Match>
</Placement>
```

Using the Shape Tracing from the [Designer Tools 1.4](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.DesignerTools/1.4.0) Module I could identify the shape of each element of the list and find where to put the template.
Using this tool, after selecting an element of the list:

1. I had on the Shape tab:
       Shape    Content
       Active Template  ~/Themes/Bootstrap/Views/Content-Cotainer-resource.cshtml
       Original Template Template  ~/Core/Contents/Views/Content.cshtml
       Display Type   Summary
2. On the template tab I had the template previous described.
3. And on the placement tab:
   **n\a**

Briefly, what I am trying to do is the same was done with [Creating lists](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-lists) on this tutorial at the **Customizing How the List is Rendered** topic, but using **projection** and instead of customize each field of an item with, customize the entire item with a template file.

Many thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @GiscardBiamby, I had some progress since I made that question, but I still have some dounts.
You can check my other question for more details of the problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108136/projector-orchard-cms-and-widget

Comment: Please be more clear on what you need..